# Rails 3 HABTM Join Table Re-use With Extra Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I have a HABTM relationship between my Students and Classrooms using a join table called ClassroomStudents to handle many students belonging to many classrooms.

A recent business requirement came up that students should be able to request memberships to a classroom, so I thought that I would just create another invitation table containing classroom_id and student_id but quickly realized my classroomstudents table already handled this so I thought about simply re-using this table. I added a boolean accepted field to my classroomstudents table, true representing a membership that has been confirmed and false being the default.

There are multiple ways in which students can be added to classrooms, one of which I want them to be accepted automatically when the relationship is built. So with the following code:

```
@classroom << @students
```

How can I also specify a true value for this boolean accepted field instead of the default of false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the default value in the database be `true`.  For example, write a migration that looks like this

```
class MakeAcceptedDefaultToTrue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :classroom_students, :accepted, :boolean, :default => true, :null => false
  end
end
```

Comment: I had considered that as well, but when I'm making a new request to join a classroom would I have to manually create the join table record and set the accepted value to false? (as opposed to being able to use something like `@classroom << @student`)

Comment: Oh, you're just asking how to make the value be not the default, whatever the default happens to be?  Sorry, didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do it manually.  If it's something you find yourself doing in multiple places, you could wrap it in a helper method.